# Call center value on background-position failes

Tags: jquery, css

got the following problem:

This works:

```
var var1 = 40+'%'; 
var var2 = 50+'%';

$some.css({'backgroundPosition': var1 + var2});

//Result: #some{background-position: 40% 50%}
```

But if i set:

```
var var1 = 'center'; // or center (without '.') 
var var2 = 50+'%';

$some.css({'backgroundPosition': var1 + var2});
```

I get nothing rendered! How can I set the "center" value via js?

Comment: have you tried var var1 = 'center '; note that last char of var1 is a white spase

Answer (score 1):

had you tried something like

```
var var1 = 'center '; // or center (without '.')
```

or

```
$some.css({'backgroundPosition': var1 + ' ' + var2});
```

?

EDIT

I think also the problem is that you are writting

> backgroundPosition

instead of

```
background-position
```

as you are between {}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed a space:

```
$some.css({'backgroundPosition': var1 + ' ' + var2});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var var1 = "center ";
var var2 = 50 + "%";

$(".content").css({"background-position" : var1 + " " + var2});
```